# Issues iterating over a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash

What I'd like to do is pass in a hash of hashes that looks something like this:

```
input = {
    "configVersion" => "someVers",
    "box" => 
    {
        "primary"  => {
            "ip" => "192.168.1.1", 
            "host" => "something"
            },
        "api" => {
            "live" => "livekey", 
            "test" => "testkey"
            }
    }
}
```

then iterate over it, continuing if the value is another hash, and generating output with it. The result should be something like this:

```
configVersion = "someVers"
box.primary.ip = "192.168.1.1"
box.primary.host = "something"
```

and so on...

I know how to crawl through and continue if the value is a hash, but I'm unsure how to concatenate the whole thing together and pass the value back up. Here is my code:

```
def crawl(input)
  input.each do |k,v|
    case v
    when Hash
      out < "#{k}."
      crawl(v)
    else
      out < " = '#{v}';"
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is: where to define `out` and how to return it all back. I'm very new to Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass strings between multiple calls of the recursive method and use them like accumulators.

This method uses an `ancestors` string to build up your dot-notation string of keys, and an output `str` that collects the output and returns it at the end of the method. The `str` is passed through every call; the `chain` variable is a modified version of the `ancestor` string that changes from call to call:

```
def hash_to_string(hash, ancestors = "", str = "")
  hash.each do |key, value|
    chain = ancestors.empty? ? key : "#{ancestors}.#{key}"
    if value.is_a? Hash
      hash_to_string(value, chain, str)
    else
      str << "#{chain} = \"#{value}\"\n"
    end
  end
  str
end

hash_to_string input
```

(This assumes you want your output to be a string formatted as you've shown above)

Answer (score 0):

This [blog post](http://www.goodercode.com/wp/convert-your-hash-keys-to-object-properties-in-ruby/) has a decent solution for the recursion and offers a slightly better alternative using the `method_missing` method available in Ruby.

In general, your recursion is correct, you just want to be doing something different instead of concatenating the output to `out`.

Comment: `method_missing` is often convenient, but as often not "better".  It involves relatively obscure control flow for many, and is very expensive to dispatch from a performance perspective.

Comment: The performance hit is very true, but I wanted to mention it as it can provide an easy/somewhat elegant solution to some problems.